# failed to register bundle identifier after changing product name under target=>build setting=>packaging

Tags: ios, xcode

After changing `product name` (from EN to Chinese) for my react native 0.70.1 app on Xcode 14.2, the uploading to app connect throws error `failed to register bundle identifier`. The build and archive of the app runs successfully.

[image]

On Xcode, the `bundle identifier` is something like this : `org.reactjs.native.example.--`. I guess the `--` shall be filled in with the new product name.  In `plist.info`, the line of `bundle name` is ${PRODUCT_NAME} and `bundle display name` is still the previous EN name.

Comment: The bundle identifier should be something like `com.yourdomain.yourappname` - You should not use `org.reactjs.native.example` unless you are working for the reacts organisation

Comment: The current name was generated by the Xcode and hasn't been modified. did you mean the bundler identifier duplication could be an issue?

Comment: You need to modify it. The default value seems to have been set when you created your new project using react native?  The product name isn't a problem. The reverse domain portion of the bundle identifier is. It needs to be your domain, not reacts

Comment: Hi `Paulw1`,  If, I mean if, the bundle identifier was not named with my domain name, will the upload fail because of that? I thought identifier can be anything but has to be unique.

Comment: Yes, it can be anything and yes it has to be unique. Apple's recommendation is that you adopt a reverse domain name format in order to reduce the chance that your bundle id is not unique. The -- will not be filled in with the product name. Your bundle id is literall `org.reacts.native.example.--`, which is not unique apparently. If your product name is in Chinese without an English localisation your may need to remove fhe `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` and hard code a value because the bundle id must be utf8